# What do the components of light velocity look like in polar coordinates?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, velocity, coordinate-systems

The Schwarzschild solution makes use of polar coordinates, and I'm wondering how the different components of velocity of light change with the position. Might I get some examples of light velocity vectors (in units of $c$ such that $\langle 1,0,0,0\rangle$ is the velocity vector for a light ray moving radially away from the black hole at the speed of light)?